# Not able to load local pdf file in react-native-view-pdf

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-view-pdf`.

It works fine if I give url of pdf:

```
<PDFView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  onError={error => console.log('onError', error)}
  onLoad={() => console.log('PDF rendered from file')}
  resource={'https://example.pdf'}
  resourceType={'url'}
/>
```

But if I try to upload local pdf file the it is giving me error:

```
<PDFView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  onError={error => console.log('onError', error)}
  onLoad={() => console.log('PDF rendered from file')}
  resource={'../../assets/pdf/new.pdf'}
  resourceType={'file'}
/>
```

I am getting error:
`onError {"message": "error: ../../assets/pdf/new.pdf"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post the stack trace or the complete error log?

Comment: did you tried `resource={require('../../assets/pdf/new.pdf')}` ?